# sort array specified indexes IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I' want to filter `NSARRAY` based on an object named id, I've specific set of Ids that I want to filter and want to be first in `NSARRAY`.

I stored the following Ids as `NSNUMEBR`

```
         NSNumber *A = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1122];
         NSNumber *B = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1345];
         NSNumber *C = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1667];
         NSNumber *D = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1223];
         NSNumber *E = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1213];
         NSNumber *F = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1123];
         NSNumber *G = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1555];
         NSNumber *H = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1666];
         NSNumber *I = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1567];
```

These are the set of ids that I want to filter and want to be first in my `NSARRAY` (Can be `NSMutableArray` for operation)

**EDIT 1:**

the NSARRAY is basically getting the id object as

```
Ids = [dict valueForKey:@"id"];
```

That selective ids are stored in NSNUMBER A to I

Comment: Your question is not clear, and your example has obvious syntax errors. Can you improve your question?

Comment: you want to clear a array? or what is that strange loop (including the assignment above) supposed to do?

Comment: @luk2302 I want to remove that indexes and then add on the top of the array.

Comment: the loop is removing that ids once so that I can add them later together,

Comment: Could you show a clearer example?

Comment: `I' want to filter NSARRAY based on an object named id` I don´t see any NSArray anywhere, I don´t see any filtering and i dont see anything like an id (ignoring the syntax error)

Comment: @luk2302 id is basically the object, I collected that in NSNUMBER

Comment: @Larme please check the edit 1

Comment: Remove them from other array, then prepend back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking, as indicated by the down votes and comments. But let's see if we can help. I think the following pseudo-code algorithm is what you are asking for:

```
MutableArray frontItems, rearItems;

for every item in sourceArray
   if item["id"] is in the collection of specific IDs
   then add item to end of frontItems
   else add item to end of rearItems

add rearItems to end of frontItems to give result
```

Write that in Objective-C and I think you have what you want.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

//Creat array have all item : A->I

```
NSNumber *A = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1122];
NSNumber *B = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1345];
NSNumber *C = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1667];
NSNumber *D = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1223];
NSNumber *E = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1213];
NSNumber *F = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1123];
NSNumber *G = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1555];
NSNumber *H = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1666];
NSNumber *I = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1567];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:A,B,C,...,I, nil];

for (NSNumber *idx in arr) {
    // To do
}
```